# Generate PDF through Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, export-to-pdf

I found a [script](https://gist.github.com/andrewroberts/8985d5d0a50c905ed43b639a97c2035f) that takes the fields from the active row in the active Google Spreadsheet and, using a Google Doc template, creates a PDF with these fields replacing the keys in the template. The keys are identified by having a `%` either side, e.g. `%Name%`.

The linked code adds a menu entry to the UI, so the user only needs to click in one cell and then select the 'Create PDF' menu option. I want to make some changes, in order to meet my needs. My context is:

1. User chooses one option in each in-cell drop-down list, respectively found in C3, C5, C7 and C9. These choices trigger filters in my sheet;
2. User clicks a button to generate a PDF report based on the sheet state;
3. The script displays a message if an invalid option was set or if the report was generated successfully;

My current code:

```
var TEMPLATE_ID = ''
var PDF_FILE_NAME = ''

function checkEntries(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
      project = ss.getRange('C3').getValue(),
      month = ss.getRange('C5').getValue(),
      year = ss.getRange('C7').getValue();

  if(project === 'all' && month === 'all' && year === 'all'){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('The report is always specific to a project in a specific year and month')
    return;
  }
}

function createPdf() {
  var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
      copyId = copyFile.getId(),
      copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
      copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
      project = ss.getRange('C3').getValue(),
      total_cost = ss.getRange('C14').getValue(),
      month = ss.getRange('C7').getValue(),
      year = ss.getRange('C9').getValue();

  var replace_values = [];
  replace_values.push(total_cost, year, month)

  for (var i = 0; i < replace_values.length; i++) {
    copyBody.replaceText('%' + replace_values[i] + '%', 
                         replace_values[i])          
  }
  copyDoc.saveAndClose()

  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  
  if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
    newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
  } 

  copyFile.setTrashed(true)

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('report generated successfully')
}
```

I link that script to a button, but it does not get cell values and does not generate the PDF. The expected behavior is generate a PDF doc, based on a Doc template, replacing placeholders with `year`, `month`, and `total_cost` variables. What I am doing wrong and I how can I achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Edit your question to include any specific errors encountered, along with the desired behavior and the current behavior.

Comment: Done. I think I could know more about the current behavior writting to logs. I'll do that and post results

Comment: You mention that you link your script to the button... well, your script has two functions. Which one is linked to the button? Note that the first function, `checkEntries`, does not call the second function, `createPDF`.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're so helpful!

Comment: @CaioIgnm I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- You can use `copyDoc` like `copyDoc.replaceText('%' + replace_values[i] + '%', replace_values[i])`.
- After `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),` is run, an error occurs at `sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],`.

  - If you want to use the sheet with the index of "0", `ss` of `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),` can be used as it.
  - In this modification, I thought that you might want to also use other index. So I used `sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];`.
- `project` of `project = ss.getRange('C3').getValue(),` is not used in `createPdf()`.
- `var replace_values = []; replace_values.push(total_cost, year, month)` is the same to `var replace_values = [total_cost, year, month];`.

  - You can also use the destructuring assignment like `[total_cost, month, year] = [sheet.getRange('C14').getValue(), sheet.getRange('C7').getValue(), sheet.getRange('C9').getValue()];` instead of `total_cost = sheet.getRange('C14').getValue(),month = sheet.getRange('C7').getValue(),year = sheet.getRange('C9').getValue();`

When these are reflected to the modified script, please modify as follows.

From :

```
var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
    copyId = copyFile.getId(),
    copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
    copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
    project = ss.getRange('C3').getValue(),
    total_cost = ss.getRange('C14').getValue(),
    month = ss.getRange('C7').getValue(),
    year = ss.getRange('C9').getValue();
var replace_values = [];
replace_values.push(total_cost, year, month)
for (var i = 0; i < replace_values.length; i++) {
  copyBody.replaceText('%' + replace_values[i] + '%', replace_values[i])
}
```

To :

```
var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
    copyId = copyFile.getId(),
    copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), // Modified
    sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
    total_cost = sheet.getRange('C14').getValue(), // Modified
    month = sheet.getRange('C7').getValue(), // Modified
    year = sheet.getRange('C9').getValue(); // Modified
var replace_values = [total_cost, year, month]; // Modified
for (var i = 0; i < replace_values.length; i++) {
  copyDoc.replaceText('%' + replace_values[i] + '%', replace_values[i]); // Modified
}
```

#### Note :

- You can also confirm the errors in your script using [Execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript).

#### References :

- [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)
- [Execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Rather than the two part "initialize then add" for `replaceValues`, why not `var replaceValues = [total_cost, year, month];`?

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your comment. I added it as one of modifications.

Comment: I also think that the use of `replaceValues` is not correct in the original script - there should be a key (surrounded by the `%` symbol) and a value that will replace it. E.g. `for (var key in values) copyDoc.replaceText("%" + key + "%", values[key]);` where values is `{year: "...", ... }`

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your additional information.